# Module to convert Drupal site to Static Html Site

Tags: theming, importing-exporting

I need some module which can convert drupal 7 site into static HTML site.
I tried with html export dev version but it wont work.
please help me if there is any other way to create static site from Drupal 7.

Comment: did you run on this page http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8874/export-deploy-drupal-site-page-to-static-no-cache

Comment: I already checked this reference and then tried html export
which does not give me output as i expect and html export for drupal 7 is dev version.